# Distinct rows from Datatable on basis of value of one column... rather than all column

Tags: c#

I have a datatable, i want to get distinct rows on the basis of value of one column instead of getting distinct rows on basis of all column in row of datatable. since we can get distinct rows as follows

```
datatableName.DefaultView.ToTable("true","ColName");
```

since in ToTable() we have to specify all column to be displayed. Please help me so that i can be able to get distinct rows having all column displyed and only one column is used to get distinct rows.

Example sample rows, which i have are as follows

```
ID Application English Spanish German
1  sam         thnks   thnkd   thkng
2  smp         thnks   thnke   thnkp
3  anp         same    same    same
```

i want to get all those rows wwhich have different spanish/German Cloumn Value against English Column Value.....

Help in this regard will be much appreciated...

Thanks in advance

Comment: Not clear what you need exactly if you provide an image or a specified format of output what u need is much better

Comment: did you find your answer? i am looking for same solution. want all columns but distinct on single column of dataset/datatable

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for how to find rows where the columns do not match, thats easy

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column2 != column3
```

But for a realy distinct you have to run distict over all the columns you need as distinct meens that the rows are not identical.

YOu could also have a sub select with distinct on 2 collumns and then join in the rest of the columns if you like.

Answer (score 0):

When you say "i want to get all those rows wwhich have different spanish/German Cloumn Value against English Column Value...", that is not what DISTINCT means, that is a filter.

You can just do this:

```
datatableName.DefaultView.RowFilter = "English <> German";
DataTable result = datatableName.DefaultView.ToTable("differentEngGer");
datatableName.DefaultView.RowFilter = null; //reset the view to not filter anything
```

Answer (score -1):

You could do

```
var x = (from r in dt.AsEnumerable() select r["ABC"]).Distinct().ToList(); //dt is the datatable
```

Hope this help

Answer (score -1):

got answer from [msdn forum here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetdataset/thread/ed9c6a6a-a93e-4bf5-a892-d8471b84aa3b/)

you can try following code.

```
datatableName.DefaultView.ToTable("true","ID","Application","English","Spanish","German");
```